# Having problems with practicing loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, break

```
import time
import random
import math

start = 1
stop = 10

for i in range(start, stop):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\ni = {}".format(i), end = "")
    count = 3 + random.randint(1,5)
    print(", count = {}".format(count))
    nums = []
    while len(nums) < count:
        for j in range(count):
            time.sleep(0.3)
            try:
                num = random.randint(-10,100)
                log = round(math.log(num),1)
            except:
                time.sleep(2)
                print("\nagain")
                break
            nums.append(log)
            print("\rnums = {}".format(nums), end = "")
```

What I want to do is giving a random integer `count` for each iteration `i`, then using a `while` loop to append the log of `num` to `nums` until the length of `nums` equals to `count`. Here `num` is a random integer between -10 and 100, and if `num` is given as 0 or below, I want to start the loop again from the very beginning of `for i in range(start, stop):`, which is `time.sleep(1)`, so that I can designate new `count` and make new `nums`.

So I executed the code above, and it starts the loop again from the beginning of `while len(nums) < count:`.

For example, what I expected was something like

```
i = 1, count = 7
nums = [4.2, 4.4, 2.9, 4.4]
again
i = 1, count = 5
nums = [3.5, 3.6, 4.2]
again
i = 1, count = 6
nums = [2.0, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 4.2, 4.5]
i = 2, count = 5
nums = [4.5, 4.1, 4.0, 3.9, 3.8]
i = 3, count = 6
nums = [4.3, 3.8]
again
i = 3, count = 5
nums = [3.0, 3.4, 4.6, 3.6, 3.1]
```

and so on

And what I got is

```
i = 1, count = 7
nums = [4.2, 4.4, 2.9, 4.4, 3.2, 2.6]
again
nums = [4.2, 4.4, 2.9, 4.4, 3.2, 2.6, 4.0, 1.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.5, 4.4, 2.9]
i = 2, count = 4

again
nums = [4.5, 4.1, 4.0, 3.9]
i = 3, count = 6
nums = [4.3, 3.8]
again
nums = [4.3, 3.8, 3.6, 2.3, 3.4, 4.6, 3.6, 3.1]
i = 4, count = 5
nums = [1.4, 3.0, 4.0, 4.4, 4.0]
i = 5, count = 7
nums = [4.4, 2.9, 3.5, 4.2, 3.6, 4.4, 4.6]
```

and so on

Comment: What is the expected output? What do you get instead?

Comment: what if ```except``` happens and so ```log``` isn't created, how will you do ```nums.append(log)```

Comment: @coderoftheday that's why I'm starting the loop from the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it all in a function and call it again whenever `num` is less than or equal to 0

```
import time
import random
import math

start = 1
stop = 10

def whatever():
    for i in range(start, stop):
        time.sleep(1)
        print("\ni = {}".format(i), end = "")
        count = 3 + random.randint(1,5)
        print(", count = {}".format(count))
        nums = []
        while len(nums) < count:
            for j in range(count):
                time.sleep(0.3)
                num = random.randint(-10,100)

                if num <= 0:
                    time.sleep(2)
                    print("\nagain")
                    whatever()
                else:
                    log = round(math.log(num),1)
                    nums.append(log)

                print("\rnums = {}".format(nums), end = "")

whatever()
```

This is where the loop will start again if `num` is less than or equal to 0

```
if num <= 0:
    time.sleep(2)
    print("\nagain")
    whatever()
```

**Output**:

```
i = 1, count = 8
nums = [4.2, 2.9, 3.8, 2.1, 4.0, 4.1, 3.8, 4.4]
i = 2, count = 5
nums = [3.4, 3.2, 3.6, 4.5]
again

i = 1, count = 8
nums = [3.5, 4.2, 4.3, 3.9, 3.5, 4.3, 1.1, 3.2]
i = 2, count = 7

again

i = 1, count = 8
nums = [2.4, 3.0, 4.5, 4.1, 4.2, 4.5, 3.6]
```